# JUnit ClassRule executes code before Spring Boot application shut down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit4

I am running a Spring Boot integration test with `org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest`.

I have written a JUnit 4 `org.junit.rules.TestRule` and I am using it as a `org.junit.ClassRule`.

It looks like this:

```
public class MyRule implements TestRule {

    public Statement apply(final Statement statement, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                // do something
                try {
                    statement.evaluate();
                } finally {
                   // clean up
                }

            }
        };
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the // clean up code is executed before the Spring Boot context is shut down.

Where do I have to put my code to execute it after the Spring application is shut down?

Comment: Try with a [Sprint TestExecutionListener](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/test-execution-listener.html)

Comment: @RomanVottner As far as I can see it they will be executed before the application shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code of all `ClassRule`s is executed first and the Spring context is torn down right before the JVM terminates (see also https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook--).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the tests of spring, I recommend using the Spring test execution listener.

Rules are JUnit's specific feature, and since the spring is integrated with JUnit as a Runner (`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`) they might interfere.

So, back to those test execution Listeners. Basically its a listener managed by Spring itself and it provides hooks to the test life-cycle where you can clean up your code
 here is an example:

```
public class MySampleListener implements TestExecutionListener {
   @Override
   public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("beforeTestClass");
   }

   @Override
   public void prepareTestInstance(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("prepareTestInstance");
   }

   @Override
   public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
       System.out.println("beforeTestMethod");
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
       System.out.println("afterTestMethod");
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
       System.out.println("afterTestClass");
   }
}
```

If you don't need all the methods, you can use `org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestExecutionListener` that provides an empty implementation for all these methods.

Now, in the test you supply an annotation `@TestExecutionListeners`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
... // stuff like @ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners(value = {MySampleListener.class, ...})
  public class MySampleTest {


   @Test
   public void testFoo() {
     //test me
   }
```

}

If you want to merge the other listeners that spring runs by default, you can use this annotation as follows:

`@TestExecutionListeners(value = MySampleListener.class,
      mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)`